# Pyenv BUILD FAILLED to install python 3.6.0 on mac OS 13.1

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

I know this problem has been beat dead but I've tried every solution I've seen to fix this error when I try to install python 3.6.0 for opencv on pyenv:

```
Installing Python-3.6.0...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 13.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/10/_qy8jd1j4sxgnyyy0r6nmj7c0000gn/T/python-build.20230708233231.54832
Results logged to /var/folders/10/_qy8jd1j4sxgnyyy0r6nmj7c0000gn/T/python-build.20230708233231.54832.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for clang++... no
configure:

  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "clang++".
  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.
  
checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Yes. I've tried:
`SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.14 pyenv install 3.6.0` 
and

Uninstall the old tools

$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

Reinstall Xcode Command line tools

$ xcode-select --install

Install python using pyenv

$ pyenv install 3.9.5

literally anything I can find I've tried and it doesnt work.
brew version: Homebrew 4.0.26

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation to you. I have tried everything. I used Anaconda to create me a virtual env with 3.6 installed details [here](https://saturncloud.io/blog/updating-python-to-a-specific-version-using-conda-a-guide/)

I had to add conda to my path using help [here](https://saturncloud.io/blog/solving-the-conda-command-not-found-issue-after-installing-anaconda3/). Conda exe was in ~/opt/Anaconda3/bin for me

After creating the virtual env the conda activate  didn't work for me. Running `conda init zsh` fixed it.

The version of 3.6 that anaconda installs is 3.6.13.

Hope this is a solution for you, if you haven't already found one!